# Creating an Excel Macro to Delete multiple rows at once

Tags: vba, excel

I found a code online and want to make edits to it.  The code is in VBA and I want the macro code to delete multiple rows rather than one.  Here is the code:

```
Sub findDelete()
    Dim c As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    c = InputBox("FIND WHAT?")

    Set Rng = Nothing

    Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(what:=c, _
        After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    Rng.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, the `Set Rng = Nothing` is meaningless where it is, it should be at the end of the sub, when `Rng` is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using find, use `Autofilter` and delete the `VisibleCells`

```
Sub findDelete()

Dim c As String, Rng As Range, wks as Worksheet

c = InputBox("FIND WHAT?")

Set wks = Sheets(1) '-> change to suit your needs
Set Rng = wks.Range("A:A").Find(c, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

    With wks

        .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, c
        Set Rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Range("A:A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Rng.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

To replace the InputBox with Multiple Values to Find / Delete Do This:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndDeleteValues()

Dim strValues() as String

strValues() = Split("these,are,my,values",",")

Dim i as Integer

For i = LBound(strValues()) to UBound(strValues())

    Dim c As String, Rng As Range, wks as Worksheet
    c = strValues(i)

    '.... then continue with code as above ...

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked out great.  Thank you.  In addition, would there be a way, rather than have the inputbox, be a way to enter multiple values to check and have them deleted as well.

Comment: @Jeff -> Yes you can do that. You can use say `Range("A1:A3")` to enter your values, then have your code loop through those values to find and delete. If you get stuck on how to do that, please post another question on S0 since it's a separate issue. (If you want post a link to that question in this comment section, so I can find it easily and help you if needed).

Comment: what i want to do is replace the input box with the multiple values to find and delete.  how do i do that?

Comment: @Jeff -> I've edited my post, but please, in the future, post separate questions in separate posts. This make searching for answers for way easier and keeps things simplified, especially if each question has a unique focus (in terms of programming).

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it up in a `While` loop.

```
Sub findDelete()
    Dim c As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    c = InputBox("FIND WHAT?")
    Set Rng = Nothing
    Do While Not Range("A:A").Find(what:=c) Is Nothing
        Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(what:=c, _
        After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        Rng.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Except, if there are many, many rows with that data this could take loads of unnecessary time. `AutoFilter` is much faster, cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code to delete rows in `Rng.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp`, what you need is the code to set the range to the rows which you want to delete. As usual in VBA, this can be done in a lot of ways:

```
'***** By using the Rng object
Set Rng = Rows("3:5")

Rng.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

Set Rng = Nothing

'***** Directly
Rows("3:5").EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
```

Your `Find` statement only finds the first occurrence of `c`, that's why it's not deleting more that one row.